# EXCEL VBA Timevalue format (hh:mm am/pm)

Tags: excel, vba

How do I set the format for timevalue for 12-hour clock without second. For example: hh:mm AM/PM. Right now I'm using `Format(TimeValue(Now), "hh:mm")` but it wont display AM/PM.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change your format string to include the indicator for `AM/PM` (based on the [VBA Format function documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx) - see the heading `User-Defined Date/Time Formats (Format Function)` roughly halfway down the page - there's no anchor to link to directly):

```
Format(TimeValue(Now), 'hh:mm AM/PM')
```

Valid choices for different displays of AM/PM values are:

> **AM/PM**
>
> Use the 12-hour clock and display an uppercase AM with any hour before noon; display an uppercase PM with any hour between noon and 11:59 P.M.
>
> **am/pm**
>
> Use the 12-hour clock and display a lowercase AM with any hour before noon; display a lowercase PM with any hour between noon and 11:59 P.M.
>
> **A/P**
>
> Use the 12-hour clock and display an uppercase A with any hour before noon; display an uppercase P with any hour between noon and 11:59 P.M.
>
> **a/p**
>
> Use the 12-hour clock and display a lowercase A with any hour before noon; display a lowercase P with any hour between noon and 11:59 P.M.
>
> **AMPM**
>   Use the 12-hour clock and display the AM string literal as defined by your system with any hour before noon; display the PM string literal as defined by your system with any hour between noon and 11:59 P.M. AMPM can be either uppercase or lowercase, but the case of the string displayed matches the string as defined by your system settings. The default format is AM/PM.

Comment: Edited. Also provided a link to the `Format` function documentation.

Comment: I truly appreciate your response. Thank you so much. Will definitely read the link that you provided later.