# How do I switch from PM/AM to 24h in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, time, vba

as 4 Leave Cover has stated his Problem with switching 24h to PM/AM - [EXCEL VBA Timevalue format (hh:mm am/pm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681900/excel-vba-timevalue-format-hhmm-am-pm)

I have exactly the opposite problem:

I use following code (t = 1,39)

```
t = wks.Range("G1").Value / 1440
wks.Range("I1").Value = Format(t, "hh:mm:ss")
```

which gives me 00:01:23 in the formula text field, but in cell it is formatted as 12:01:23 AM. The problem is: In cell I want it to be formatted as 00:01:23 as well. If possible - I would even like to have it just minutes and seconds. - but "nn:ss" gives me 1:23:00 AM and "mm:ss" gives me 12:23:00 PM.

I have also tried a TimeSerial-Function but the output in cell is basically the same as mentioned above- In opposite to debug.print however, which gives me the desired results - not in a cell though:

```
Public Function FromTimeToDecimal(ByVal t As Double) As Date
FromTimeToDecimal = TimeSerial(0, Fix(t), (t - Fix(t)) * 60)
End Function
```

So basically I am out of clue at the moment

(country setting is set to Germany - in case that matters)

Comment: You need to set the `NumberFormat` of the ***cell*** - otherwise Excel will simply reformat it after you write to it.  `"mm:ss;@"` or `"h:mm:ss;@"` should work.

Comment: Sadly that does have the desired effect - thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can replicate your problem, but also easily fix it by setting the `NumberFormat` as Comintern suggests which you seem unsure about.

To do this programmatically, do the following:

```
wks.Range("I1").NumberFormat = "General"
wks.Range("I1").Value = Format(t, "nn:ss")
```

Comment: @Marc happy to help!