# How To Pop Up A Calendar When Clicking A Specific Cell In Excel, and have the date and time insert in that cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have used the following code to select a cell and have the date picker popup. It works fine. however, for my application I need the user to input the date as well as the time(am/pm). How can I add the time alongside the date? When I format the cells to show date and time, the time defaults to 12:00 AM. Please advise.

*userform*

```
    Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
 On Error Resume Next
   Dim xRg As Object
   For Each xRg In Selection.Cells
      xRg.Value = DateClicked
   Next xRg
   Unload Me
End Sub
```

*sheet1*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M4:M300")) Is Nothing Then UserForm3.Show
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want the userform to be auto-populated with the current date/time once the userform has been shown via the selection change?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681900/excel-vba-timevalue-format-hhmm-am-pm as a reference for formatting the time.

Comment: Yes, that would be much better. The current date and time will be all the user should need to enter in that cell.

Comment: If you don't want the current time to be used you'll have to update UserForm3 to allow for a time to be entered somewhere and this will have to be added to the date before passing in the `DateClicked` argument.

Comment: If you only want the current date and time entered in a cell you could use the code `Target.Value = Now` within a `WorkSheet_BeforeDoubleClick` event procedure - double click the cell and it will add the current date/time to that cell.

Comment: I do not have a textbox in the userform. I'm using microsoft datepicker. The user would select a cell in the range and the date picker will popup for them to choose a date. I would like to keep this function - only adding the time once the date is selected.

Comment: WorkSheet_BeforeDoubleClick event procedure.. worked for my application. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the my question in the comment is correct, you can do either of the following... In the userform (1 of two ways):

1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M4:M300")) Is Nothing Then UserForm3.Show
    UserForm3.TextBox1.Value = Format(Time, "hh:mm AM/PM") 'Assumes you have a textbox in the Userform
End Sub
```

2

```
Private Sub UserForm3_Initialize()
    TextBox1.Value = Format(Time, "hh:mm AM/PM")
End Sub
```

---

From selectionchange:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M4:M300")) Is Nothing Then UserForm3.Show
    ActiveCell.Formula = Format(Time, "hh:mm AM/PM") 'Activecell as the current range
End Sub
```

If you want somethign sequential in the Excel only, you might want an if statement like:

```
If ActiveCell.Offset(-1,0).Value="" Then Exit Sub
```